# Bash History missing from Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, bash

After an OS update, my bash history is suddenly gone - typing "history" at a terminal window (sudo or standard) yields only the commands entered after the upgrade.

What could have happened here?

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case, I found that the history had gotten into a strange state.

Nothing was present in the `.bash_history` file, however, there were plenty of saved sessions in the `.bash_sessions` folder of the user root (e.g. `~`).

Once inside the `.bash_sessions` folder, I found there was a file with a GUID and a `.historynew` extension.

Ex:

```
~/.bash_sessions/{GUID}.historynew
```

That file contained the lost commands, but somehow was no longer attached to the saved history for the user. From there I simply piped the output and appended to the .bash_history file, and started a new session and everything was back. One way to do this:

```
cat {GUID}.historynew >> ../.bash_history
```